# Delete line in each text files if the first field value is greater than 400

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a large number of txt files. the format of each txt files is similar to this

```
200 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.4
500 0.4 0.9 0.9 0.1
```

I am trying to delete each line in each txt file that has the first field value greater than 400. So the above file should only contain this now:

```
200 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.4
```

Code

```
for file in *.txt; do 
        echo "$(awk '{ if ($1 < 401) print }' *.txt)" > tmp && mv tmp *.txt 
done 
rm -f tmp
```

but this doesn't work as it moves all the files to the next text file.

Comment: Rarely is `echo $( some_command )` materially different from just writing `some_command`

Comment: Certainly no material benefit, but it can make things at least slightly worse.  It depends on how much and what kind of output it produces.  For starters, unquoted it would convert newlines in the output to spaces, so the entire output is only one line. And, whether quoted or unquoted, it also wastes CPU & real time - e.g. on my system `time echo "$(find /usr/share/doc/ | wc)"` takes about 1.7 seconds vs about 0.8 seconds as `time find /usr/share/doc/ | wc` (with repeated runs to eliminate caching differences).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refer to `file` in your loop; there’s also no need to use `echo`:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
        awk '{ if ($1 < 401) print }' < "$file" > tmp && mv -- tmp "$file"
done 
rm -f tmp
```

The AWK code can be simplified too:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
        awk '$1 < 401' < "$file" > tmp && mv -- tmp "$file"
done 
rm -f tmp
```

To match your requirement exactly, the test should be changed:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
        awk '!($1 > 400)' < "$file" > tmp && mv -- tmp "$file"
done 
rm -f tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GNU awk (which you almost certainly are if you're using Linux), you can use GNU awk's in-place edit library, and you don't even need a shell `for` loop or any temporary files to do it.

```
 awk -i inplace '$1 < 401' ./*.txt
```

This will remove all lines where field 1 is > 400 from each text file.  It works by first loading GNU awk's `inplace` library, and then only outputting lines where `$1 < 401` evaluates to true.

If you want awk to make a backup copy of each original file (e.g. with a .bak filename extension) before it changes it, you can use awk's INPLACE_SUFFIX variable:

```
 awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '$1 < 401' ./*.txt
```

---

Note: unlike some other programs (e.g. `sed` and `perl`), which have a `-i` option for in-place edit, GNU awk's `-i` option is short for `--include`...i.e. include the gawk library named in the next argument.  It's this library (called "inplace") which provides the in-place edit functionality.

Comment: Beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.

Comment: Yeah, I personally wouldn't use awk for this, I'd use perl.  e.g. something like `perl -i -lane 'print if $F[0] <= 400' ./*.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code like this to do the work:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
        awk '{ if ($1 < 401) print }' < "$file" > tmp && mv -- tmp "$file" 
done 
rm -f tmp
```

But be careful when overwrite original file, better create modified files in different directory (something like): `mv tmp modified/$file` and do not forget to create this directory before copy files there.

And if you define the logic as "greater than 400" you `if` should be: `$1 <= 400` (the number can be 400.1)